# Latex - buffer overflow with babel.def (texlive)

Tags: latex, buffer-overflow, pdflatex

I have a problem while trying to use latex on xubuntu. It always dies with buffer overflow at babel package. I have the most recent version of TexLive. Makefile:

```
buf_size=100000 pdflatex projekt
bibtex $(CO)
buf_size=100000 pdflatex $(CO)
buf_size=100000 pdflatex $(CO)
```

And the first pdlfatex dies with buffer overflow. Here is Log:

```
rm -f *.dvi *.log projekt.blg projekt.bbl projekt.toc *.aux projekt.out projekt.lof
rm -f projekt.pdf
rm -f *~
buf_size=100000 pdflatex projekt
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./projekt.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, et
hiopic, arabic, farsi, pinyin, mongolian, bulgarian, serbianc, serbian,   mongoli
anlmc, russian, ukrainian, usenglishmax, ukenglish, armenian, friulan, irish, d
anish, turkish, romanian, bokmal, nynorsk, latvian, slovenian, hungarian, kurma
nji, romansh, icelandic, dutch, latin, welsh, piedmontese, croatian, finnish, s
wedish, estonian, lithuanian, uppersorbian, french, basque, ngerman, ngerman-x-
2013-05-26, german, swissgerman, german-x-2013-05-26, ibycus, ancientgreek, mon
ogreek, greek, tamil, bengali, telugu, oriya, malayalam, gujarati, hindi, kanna
da, marathi, sanskrit, panjabi, assamese, italian, georgian, thai, turkmen, afr
ikaans, esperanto, indonesian, interlingua, coptic, polish, portuguese, catalan
, galician, spanish, czech:IL2, czech:T1, czechX, slovak:IL2, slovak:T1, slovak
X, loaded.
(./fitthesis.cls
Document Class: fitthesis 2007/04/13 Sablona pro BP/DP
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/home/ferymelchiah/texmf/tex/generic/csh-babel/switch.def)
(/home/ferymelchiah/texmf/tex/generic/csh-babel/czech.ldf
(/home/ferymelchiah/texmf/tex/generic/csh-babel/babel.def)
(/home/ferymelchiah/texmf/tex/generic/csh-babel/babel.def)
(/home/ferymelchiah/texmf/tex/generic/csh-babel/babel.def)
```

with  the last line it goes on until...

```
(/home/ferymelchiah/texmf/tex/generic/csh-babel/babel.def)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex: buffer overflow at file ../../../texk/web2c/pdftexdir/
  utils.c, line 183
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have no idea what is wrong. If somebody could push me towards the solution, I would be most grateful.